# compute shader won't write into buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-4

I am trying to use a compute shader to write into a buffer.

Setting up the buffer:

```
glCreateBuffers(1, &m_ssbo);
glNamedBufferStorage(m_ssbo, 1920 * 1080 * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), nullptr, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_READ_BIT | GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
```

Compute Shader:

```
#version 450 core
layout (local_size_x = 1) in;
layout(std430, binding = 0) restrict writeonly buffer SSBO {
    vec4 color[];
};
void main() {
    color[0] = vec4(1., 0., 0., 1.);
}
```

Dispatch and Reading:

```
m_comp_prog.use();
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, m_ssbo);
glDispatchCompute(1, 1, 0);
glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);

{
    auto * ptr = m_ssbo.map(0, static_cast<unsigned int>(sizeof(GLfloat)) * 4, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);
    GLfloat * fptr = static_cast<GLfloat *>(ptr);
    std::cout << fptr[0] << std::endl;
    m_ssbo.unmap();
}
```

The output however is 0 and not 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if you are never executing the shader:

```
glDispatchCompute(1, 1, 0);
```

Although not mentioned in the reference, [this page](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_Shader#Dispatch) indicatest that parsing 0 to one of the arguments is not allowed. This can be explained since `num_group_x * num_group_y * num_group_z` workgroups are created, which means that non are created with this parameters (1*1*0 = 0).

To fix the problem, try to call

```
glDispatchCompute(1, 1, 1);
                        ^
```

instead, which will create exactly one workgroup.